# Question on the Sākta conception of Mukti

Tags: tantra, agamas, shakti, shaktism, mukti

While reading about the conception of Mukti in Shaktism, [I came across the following -](https://archive.org/details/20210823_20210823_0521/page/n35/mode/2up?view=theater)

> This Absolution, advocated by the Sakta philosophers differs only
> slightly from the Absolution advocated by the Upanishads. The
> difference is subtle , but important. **In the nirabhasa mukti of
> Saktas, the consciousness is not manifest, while in the mukti
> advocated by the Upanishads,the soul is of the very nature of
> consciousness which of course is manifest. In Nirabhasa mukti , the
> nature of Sakti is neither sentient nor insentient. Such a description
> of mukti is tantamount to the notion of the Nihilistic Buddhist term
> ‘Nirvana’ which says that mukti is of the nature of sunya or void.**

I would like to know if there are any references of this Sākta conception of nirābhāsa mukti in any of the Sākta purānas or Sākta Agamas.

Comment: brilliant question! I never heard that there is a saktadarshana sutra!